# Is it possible to get a hierarchical view of my project dependencies in Jenkins?

Tags: maven, jenkins, dependencies, project

We are using the latest version of Jenkins CI and we have a large number of projects, which have Maven dependencies on other projects. We also are using Jenkins views to group associated projects together.

I would like to be able to generate a graphical representation of the project hierarchy within a view. I am aware that if I select a project that I can see the upstream projects, but going through approximately 40 projects, writing this down and compiling it into a tree would be tedious, time-consuming and error-prone.

Does anyone know of a technique or plugin for Jenkins that could achieve this? Ideally it would work against all the projects within a view.

I would prefer an automated technique rather than performing it manually, since this process would need to be run periodically (say once a month) for a management report.

**Update**

Having investigated this question, I am not averse to writing a script to query the Jenkins API to get the JSON or XML for the projects within a view and then asking each for its upstream projects. But I'd rather save myself some work and using someone else's tool :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use Maven to generate the dependencies for each project (http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/tree-mojo.html).

It won't give you a dependency tree for all your Jenkins projects though. Maybe you could pull from all maven outputs and create your own? Or maybe (not really) create a super project in which all modules are your existing projects (again, not really).

Comment: Interesting idea. I am investigating that plugin now. Still, I would have preferred a Jenkins plugin :)

Answer (score 0):

There is a **[Downstream Buildview](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Downstream+buildview+plugin)** plugin. It's per job, and it displays job names, but if you job names are named after maven modules, it shouldn't be an issue.